# PHP Calendar library

Tags: php, web-applications

I have to modify a simple hotel booking system to be able to show a calendar of a given week or daterange.

I need to have it so that for each day I can show room availability and color code it as neccessary.

I would also need to make it so that rates would automatically be adjusted/calulated for weekends.

Is there a library or inbuilt functionality that allows for displaying several days each with additional fields and is able to identify days as weekends?

Comment: Not unless you're willing to work it out through the code. There is no magic, only magic-like effort to make something happen which appears like magic, but is really exactly known in advance.

Comment: What do you mean? A calendar library that can display date ranges in a variety of ways and tell if a day is a weekend or weekday seems like elementary functionality that would be used in many apps. Is there really no common library?

Answer (score 0):

The [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) plugin can probably get you most of the way there, but you will have to do some AJAX requests to your PHP scripts to determine what date ranges are valid (assuming you have this stuff in a database).

Comment: That isn't really useful as I don't want things calculated clientside, and I would need the display to be quite a lot larger to allow for additional fields being displayed with each day.

Comment: Ah, well in that case consider [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/). Note that although the rendering is client-side, the data can be pulled from the server.

Comment: Hmm, it looks interesting. I was still looking for something php based as that would be simpler, but even so. Can FullCalendar tell weekdays apart from weekends? For example, if I had an entry on Friday and Dragged it to Saturday, would the database be updated and a new rate able to be calculated? (weekend rate vs weekday rate)

Comment: Yep, you can get a callback when an event is dragged and perform an ajax request back to your php script.